# Debug buildout with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, plone, pdb, plone-4.x

I'm trying to fix my buildout. It seems there is a problem with a version of a package we use.

In my Dockerfile I put

```
COPY buildout.cfg /plone/instance/
RUN buildout -vvv -D
```

in order to find more about the error I receive.

Then on `docker-compose build` the debugger starts

```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py(166)call_subprocess()
-> % repr(args)[1:-1])
(Pdb)
```

and fails immediately after this with:

```
ERROR: Service 'plone' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c buildout -vvv -D' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So, it is completely useless. I can't investigate the problem.

Any advice how to debug this issue?

Comment: Do you get any traceback from running `buildout`?

Comment: @Mathias, no. I solved it reproducing the error without docker in a simple buildout.